# Javascript and PHP combination not working, dont know if I done it right

Tags: javascript, php, html

I dont really know how to explain what I'm trying to do in the title but what I'm trying to do is I'm making an admin page where I can change my header and footer color across all pages with a button when inputting a color. so I wanted to include it all in one php file so it gets the color input and echos a javascript command that goes my :root property in my css and puts in the information then exits the .php file.

I get no errors but for some reason when I press submit my colors do not change. Any ideas or help on what I could do?

PHP

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $primaryColorChange = $_POST['primaryChange'];
    
    
    require_once 'dbh-inc.php';
    require_once 'functions.inc.php';

    if (empty($primaryColorChange)) {
        header('location: ../adminPage.php?error=emptyinput');
        exit();
    }
}
else {
    header('location: ../adminPage.php?error=none');
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
     'const root = document.querySelector(":root");',
     'root.style.setProperty("--clr-primary", "<?php echo $primaryColorChange; ?>");',
     '</script>'
;
    exit();
}
```

PHP/JAVASCRIPT

```
        <h1>Input to change primary colors (header, footer, service borders)</h1>
        
        <form action="includes/changeColors.inc.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="primaryChange" placeholder="#12345;">
        <br></br>
        <input type="submit" name="changeColor" value="Submit">
        <br></br>
        </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems to be echoing PHP from javascript, this is imposible, you should  use some sort of api. The PHP code you are printing will print as raw text.

Use string joins. like this:

```php
echo '
    <script>
        console.log("' + $myVar + '");
    </script>
';
```

you can also try using regexp:

```php
$varA = "Hey";
$varB = "Hi";

$script = "
    <script>
        console.log('{{ varA }}', '{{ varA }}');
    </script>
";

$script = str_replace("{{ varA }}", $varA);
$script = str_replace("{{ varB }}", $varB);

echo $script;
```

Note: Your code isnt very good anyways due to the fact your echoing js, **Do not mix code!!!**

Use things like websockets, RestAPI, etc...

Comment: 'root.style.setProperty("--clr-primary", "' + $primaryColorChange + '");' I changed it to this and it doesnt work still

Comment: Also NOTE that ' can only be inside of "" and "" cna only be inside of ''  and '' inside of '' that are inside of "" are also fine. You can also escape strings

Comment: hmmm I'm not very experienced in php and javascript so I don't really know what to do, I'm just trying to get this to permanently change my css root variable

Comment: I've been stuck on this now for a couple hours, kind of lost :(

Comment: There are many better ways of doign this, google how to change css propetys and variables with js

Comment: No, the script is echo-ing javascript including a php-variable. Perfectly valid. If the script ever gets to that part.

Comment: @Michel Why dont you try it then, echoing php from a string is invalid, use eval or join the script with a var, but as a fact, echoign php wont work

Comment: @nullcoder You're right, didn't look hard enough. He's not concatenating.